Не могу понять как написать код для выявления закономерности отношения NPL займов по столбцу status к сумме платежа столбца amount
Вот более подробное описание, что нужно сделать:

Как проиллюстрировать изменение отношение Non-performing займов к общей выдаче по полю amount до сегодняшнего дня
К NPL платежам будем относить status = ['overdue','potential default', 'defaulted'].
Не пойму какой метод или объединение методов использовать в данном случае.
Вот ссылка на данные https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G4PdDVHzcpnjC-9_V1OjxLczgUSeN0nr/view?usp=drivesdk

